# Unable to extract text using TIKA

Tags: java, parsing, apache-tika

We have a pdf which was a hand-written document and converted to pdf using a scanner. I am using TIKA 1.13 but not able to extract text form such file.After parsing I am only getting "\n\n" as text. Here is my code :

```
Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
ContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
PDFParserConfig pdfConfig = new PDFParserConfig();
pdfConfig.setExtractInlineImages(true);
ParseContext parseContext = new ParseContext();
parseContext.set(PDFParserConfig.class, pdfConfig);
parseContext.set(Parser.class, parser);
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata, parseContext);
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: `was a hand-written document and converted to pdf`, so the PDF is an image. There is no text in the PDF. You can try to convert the image to text with an OCR tool or the scanners build-in OCR does'nt extract any text.

Comment: Can TIKA help me extracting text from such pdf which is basically an image?

Comment: Did you [try following the Apache Tika documentation on enabling OCR support](http://wiki.apache.org/tika/TikaOCR)?

Comment: If I try to run tesseract command with scanned pdf, it gives me an error "unsupported image type". Should I first convert my pdf to an image file and then use TIKA with tesseract config? Also in production I can't install tesseract so how should I add dependencies for tesseract in my java spring service?

Comment: Right, tesseract can't read pdfs, you have to either use tesseract via Tika or convert/extract the images in the right format.  If you can't install tesseract, I think this may be a non-starter.

Answer (score 0):

PDF comes in two basic flavors. In what I like to call pure pdf the text is embedded in a markup language that serves the same function as html tagging, word markup, etc. Text can be recovered from this type of pdf.
The other type is what you get when you save a word document as pdf. Each page of the original document is converted to an image, then the images are embedded in a pdf framework that supports paging. Extraction of the this time gives you a collection of images. These may or may not be amenable to OCR processing.